# The number of 3-element sets that intersect with a specific 3-element set only once

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

We consider 3-element subsets of {1,2,...,n}, then given such a subset $A = \{a,b,c\}$, how many other 3-element subsets, say $B$, are there with $|A \cap B| = 1$?

$n=3$ and $n=4$ can be easily counted, there are none and one respectfully for any $A$. We also have $n=5$ has three such subsets $B$ for any $A$. This is easier to count "manually" as by the pigeonhole principle two subsets always contain at least one shared element. But for $n \geq 6$, this isn't the case. How might we in general count such $B$?

Comment: How many subsets of size $3$ contain $a$ but neither $b$ nor $c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that we have to find number of sets B of the form {a, x, y}. As we already have chosen a, we have yet to choose 2 more elements from n-1. But from those n-1 we cant choose 2, those are {b, c}, so we have to choose 2 elements from n-1-2=n-3. Number of ways to do this is equal to C(n-3,2). We can argue in the same manner for the elements b and c. So we get the answer : 3C(n-3,2).

Do you see why n<5 must be dealt separately?

Also, it's not hard to generalize this problem.

Comment: I see, thank you! I am curious, what if we wanted to look at two subsets $A,B$, and find a third $C$ such that $|A\cap B| = |B \cap C| = |C \cap A| = 1$?